# Ctrlp Vim Plugin

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I am using the CtrlP plugin for Vim. For some reason though I can only access the file search when I type in :CtrlP, but not when I hit the actual keys CtrlP. Any thoughts? I don't have any custom key mappings.

Here is my key mapping for vim:

```
n  <NL>        *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<C-j>")<CR>
n  <C-K>       *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<C-k>")<CR>
n  <CR>        *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap('o')<CR>
n  ?           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("?")<CR>
n  A           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("A")<CR>
n  B           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("B")<CR>
n  CD          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("CD")<CR>
n  C           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("C")<CR>
n  D           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("D")<CR>
n  F           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("F")<CR>
n  I           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("I")<CR>
n  J           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("J")<CR>
n  K           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("K")<CR>
n  O           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("O")<CR>
n  P           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("P")<CR>
n  R           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("R")<CR>
n  T           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("T")<CR>
n  U           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("U")<CR>
n  <NL>        *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<C-j>")<CR>
n  <C-K>       *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<C-k>")<CR>
n  <CR>        *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap('o')<CR>
n  ?           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("?")<CR>
n  A           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("A")<CR>
n  B           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("B")<CR>
n  CD          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("CD")<CR>
n  C           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("C")<CR>
n  D           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("D")<CR>
n  F           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("F")<CR>
n  I           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("I")<CR>
n  J           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("J")<CR>
n  K           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("K")<CR>
n  O           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("O")<CR>
n  P           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("P")<CR>
n  R           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("R")<CR>
n  T           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("T")<CR>
n  X           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("X")<CR>
n  cd          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("cd")<CR>
n  e           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("e")<CR>
n  f           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("f")<CR>
n  gi          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("gi")<CR>
n  gs          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("gs")<CR>
n  go          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("go")<CR>
n  go          *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("go")<CR>
n  i           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("i")<CR>
n  m           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("m")<CR>
n  o           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("o")<CR>
n  p           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("p")<CR>
n  q           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("q")<CR>
n  r           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("r")<CR>
n  s           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("s")<CR>
n  t           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("t")<CR>
n  u           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("u")<CR>
n  x           *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("x")<CR>
n  <2-LeftMouse> *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<2-LeftMouse>")<CR>
n  <LeftRelease> *@<LeftRelease>:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<LeftRelease>")<CR>
n  <MiddleRelease> *@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("<MiddleRelease>")<CR>
n  <C-P>       * :<C-U>CtrlP<CR>
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
```

Comment: see this line `n  <C-P>       * :<C-U>CtrlP<CR>` it means that you can call the ctrlp plugin via `Ctrl+p` ... maybe a restart of the terminal will do the job.

Comment: I tried restarting the terminal. But whenever I hit ctrl-p it says "NERDTree: cannot jump to parent".

Comment: In that case it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: If I close NerdTree and hit Ctrl + p, nothing happens. I do not have any special config in my .vimrc for NerdTree.

Comment: I guess somewhere in the NerdTree plugin it binds <C-P> to some NerdTree function. You should find this and change it.

Comment: Seem like the nerdkey key mapping of "P" to "*@:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("P")<CR>" is interfering with the "P" in "<C-P>" mapping.  Even if you close nerdtree, the mappings will still be made. You have to ensure that "P" is not being mapped in normal mode.

Comment: How do you configure `<c-p>` mapping to invoke CtrlP?
Actually, ctrlp.vim provides the way to configure mapping through a variable `g:ctrlp_map`, so you just put a line below in your .vimrc:
`let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'`